# How to add NodeTypes to ServiceFabric with VMScaleSet and specific configuration (with datadisks for example) to an existing Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

We have a SF cluster with VMSS and a 5-node instance on size StandardA2m_V2, but the disk storage on these vm's is running out of space. We're planning to add a datadisk to these VM's and set the sf-datafolder to these datadisks.

At first I tried to add datadisks to our VMSS. But a few months ago when we setup the cluster, we configured the scale set with unmanaged disks. To add datadisks to the vm's, we had to change the nodes. 
Updating the resources.azure.com with [Azure virtual machine scale sets and attached data disks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-attached-disks) didn't work out because of the unmanaged disks.

Then I tried to add nodetypes to our existing cluster with PowerShell, and use 'Add-AzureRmServiceFabricNodeType' from this link: [How to add new Node Type to deployed Service Fabric cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44323742/how-to-add-new-node-type-to-deployed-service-fabric-cluster). But then I can't pass my specific VM configuration with datadisks. Nodetype is just a string that is used for naming. And the vmsku parameter is for the 'size'.

I also found [Azure Service Fabric node types and virtual machine scale sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes) but ending up in 'how to' then...

I managed to setup a new cluster, via armtemplate, with the specific configuration in VMSS and every VM with it's own datadisk. But actually I want to update my existing cluster. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can create and add VMSS to existing cluster with whatever configuration and sku you like; using placement constraints, you can migrate your services to this scaled out capacity. Drain down existing scale set you no longer want, and remove.

Comment: Reference document that describes this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade-primary-nodetype-vm

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create an arm template with your existing configuration and modify existing vmss in the template\add another node type. A good starting point for such a template is "Automation script" or resources.azure.com

You would need to add another nodeType to the SF resource as well.

Answer (score 0):

I will guide you to this answer as first step:
[Update WadCfg "only" of existing Azure Service Fabric cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50352796/update-wadcfg-only-of-existing-azure-service-fabric-cluster/50355527#50355527)

You will have to:

- Export the ARM template for your existing cluster, as link above
- Modify it with new settings and configurations(Keep in mind that changes to existing settings might break the cluster, for example, change SKUs on primary nodes are not allowed)
- Publish the updated template to your azure subscription

> I recommend you first try it in a test cluster, the export template
>   not always export all the required settings and you might face issues
>   during the process.